# Lag when using insert in VIM

Tags: vim

I am using VIM on Rhel 8 on AWS but lately there is a very noticeable lag after pressing insert key, so much that sometimes I close and open again it works sometimes but sometimes not.

This isn't a production unit so there isn't much load on it either.

What should be done to debug or resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What if you run Vim via `vim -u NONE`? Does it show the same behavior?